# How to do a Select in another Select with Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, with-statement

I must do this query in another `Select` in Postgresql :

```
SELECT COUNT(tn.autoship_box_transaction_id) 
FROM memberships.autoship_box_transaction tn 
WHERE tn.autoship_box_id = b.autoship_box_id
```

Do I must use the clause `WITH` ?

Comment: Can you also share how you plan to apply this query? There are several ways to combine sql queries, CTE (aka WITH clause) is certainly one of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as the query produces a single data element, you can use it in place of an attribute:

```
SELECT (
          SELECT COUNT(tn.autoship_box_transaction_id) 
            FROM memberships.autoship_box_transaction tn 
           WHERE tn.autoship_box_id = b.autoship_box_id
       ) AS cnt
     , other_column
  FROM wherever
     ;
```

Have a look at [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/1e218/2) demonstrating the use case.

This method often comes with a performance penalty if the db engine actually iterates over the result set and performs the query on each record encountered.

The db engine's optimizer may be smart enough to avoid the extra cost (and it should in the fiddle's toy example), but you have to look at the explain plan to be sure.

Note that its mostly an issue with 'correlated subqueries', ie. queries embedded as shown which depend on the embedding. Your example example appears to be of this kind as you use a table alias `b` which isn't defined anywhere.

There might be the option of moving the subselect to the `from` clause (**beware**: This statement is for explanatory purposes only; you must adapt it to your use case, I am just wild guessing here):

```
SELECT stats.cnt
     , b.other_column
  FROM b_table b
  JOIN (
          SELECT COUNT(tn.autoship_box_transaction_id) cnt
               , tn.autoship_box_id
            FROM memberships.autoship_box_transaction tn 
        GROUP BY tn.autoship_box_id
       ) stats
    ON (stats.autoship_box_id = b.autoship_box_id)
     ;
```

Comment: I try this and it's work very well. But When I add this second query in the first Select, I'm not able to add the second JOIN:

JOIN staging.memberships_autoship a ON a.id = b.autoship_id

SELECT stats.cnt2, stats2.cnt3,stats1.cnt1
  FROM staging.memberships_autoship_box b
  JOIN (
          SELECT COUNT(bn.autoship_box_id) cnt1,bn.autoship_box_id
            FROM staging.memberships_autoship_box bn 
        GROUP BY bn.autoship_box_id
       ) stats1
   ON (stats1.autoship_box_id = a.id)

Answer (score 6):

There are two options. You can either use the `with` clause, like so:

```
WITH some_count AS (
   SELECT COUNT(tn.autoship_box_transaction_id) 
   FROM memberships.autoship_box_transaction tn 
   WHERE tn.autoship_box_id = b.autoship_box_id
)
SELECT * FROM some_count;
```

Or the second option is to use a sub-query, like so:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    SELECT COUNT(tn.autoship_box_transaction_id) 
    FROM memberships.autoship_box_transaction tn 
    WHERE tn.autoship_box_id = b.autoship_box_id
  );
```

Comment: Why the result of this query is always one : 

SELECT stats1.cnt1
  FROM staging.memberships_autoship_box b
  JOIN staging.memberships_autoship a ON a.id = b.autoship_box_id
  JOIN (
          SELECT COUNT(bn.autoship_box_id) cnt1,bn.autoship_box_id
            FROM staging.memberships_autoship_box bn 
        GROUP BY bn.autoship_box_id
       ) stats1
   ON (stats1.autoship_box_id = a.id)